# Where should i use setState?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

In my react native project, i am trying to make a basic currency converter. In home.js you can see a component which name is InputWithButton. This component has a button which has a buttonText and it's value baseCurrency. When i click this button, CurrencyList screen is open. In CurrencyList there is a flatlist which has currency values. I can selected a value in flatlist in CurrencyList and i can send this value to the home screen with `this.props.navigation.navigate('Home',{selected:item})`   but when i back to home screen with back button i dont know how to change buttonText's value in InputWithButton's component. i dont know where should i use setState?

## Home.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, Button} from 'react-native';
import {InputWithButton} from '../components/TextInput';

//const TEMP_BASE_CURRENCY = 'USD';
//const TEMP_CONVERT_CURRENCY = 'GBP';

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      baseCurrency: 'TRY', //Başlangıç olarak sayfa açıldığında gelecek olan değerler
      convertCurrency: 'USD',

      amount: null,
      result: '',
      date: '',
    };
    //const selected = this.props.route.params;
  }

  calculate = () => {
    const amount = this.state.amount;

    let url =
      'https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=' + this.state.baseCurrency;
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET',
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        const date = data.date;
        const result = (
          data.rates[this.state.convertCurrency] * amount
        ).toFixed(2);

        this.setState({
          result,
          date,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  handleChangeText = (text) => {
    //Yazıda değişim algılandığında api işlemleri başlasın

    this.setState(
      {
        amount: text,
      },
      this.calculate,
    );
  };

  handlePressBaseCurrency = () => {
    //flatlist sayfası açılsın
    const {navigation} = this.props;
    navigation.navigate('CurrencyList');
  };

  handlePressConvertCurrency = () => {
    //flatlist sayfası açılsın
  };

  render() {
    const {baseCurrency, convertCurrency, result} = this.state;
    return (
      <View>
        <InputWithButton
          buttonText={baseCurrency}
          onPress={this.handlePressBaseCurrency}
          keyboardType="numeric"
          onChangeText={(text) => this.handleChangeText(text)}
        />
        <InputWithButton
          editable={false}
          buttonText={convertCurrency}
          onPress={this.handlePressConvertCurrency}
          value={result}
        />
        <Button
          title="Ceviri"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Ceviri')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

## CurrencyList.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, FlatList, Text} from 'react-native';
import currencies from '../data/currencies';

import {ListItem, Separator} from '../components/List';
const temp_base_currency = 'CAD';

class CurrencyList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedItem: '',
    };
  }

  handlePress = (item) => {
    this.setState({
      selectedItem: item, //__
    });
    // const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    // navigate('Home', {clickedItem: this.state.selectedItem});

    //Tıklandığında beklesin

    this.props.navigation.navigate('Home', {selected: item}); //__
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          renderItem={({item}) => (
            <ListItem
              onPress={() => this.handlePress(item)}
              text={item}
              selected={item === this.state.selectedItem} //__
            />
          )}
          data={currencies}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={Separator}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default CurrencyList;
```

Comment: You should store the state at the highest level where you use the state. You use it in the Home page, and the currency list component, so the homepage sounds like a good choice. If the currency list component is not a direct descendant (or close to) of the Home page, then store the currency in context or a third party store. It really depends how you are using it throughout your app.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without using  context,redux?

Comment: You can store it in the Home component without using context or Redux, but you might end up doing some prop-drilling if the CurrencyList is not a direct (or close) descendant. Is there a reason you want to avoid context? Context is really quite simple and built into React.